# Difference between calling a script from cmd and from a scheduled task

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I am currently trying to execute a script I wrote in Python (and then compiled into an exe) when my computer starts. This script simply downloads a file and copies it at a specified location in my computer. Here is a portion of the code I am using :

```
def DownCopy(url,dst):
    import shutil

    """ Download and copy file """
    fn = os.path.basename(urllib.url2pathname(url))
    filename, unused = urllib.urlretrieve(url,fn)


    #if remote file change set exec permission
    if filename != url and not url.startswith('file:///'):
        os.chmod(filename, stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR)

    #check if target directory exist, if not create it
    dstDir = os.path.dirname(dst)
    if not os.path.exists(dstDir):
        os.mkdir(dstDir)

    #copy
    shutil.copy(filename, dst)
```

When I exec this script using the `cmd` shell, it does work : my file is downloaded, the folder is created and my file copied in it. However, if I call this script from a scheduled task (authority : system), nothing happens, and the `Last Result` field is set to `0xfffff`.

So basically, what is the difference between calling this script from the cmd shell and from a scheduled task ? The only difference I can notice here is the user which launches the script. Using the cmd shell, the script is being executed by the current user, while it is being executed by system when called by the scheduled task. But I don't see any reason why my script would not work when called by system...

I followed Caspar's advise and I get the following result :

- Outputing the result of the scheduled task gives me a `[Errno 13] : Acces Denied` error. I checked the permissions on the folder I want to copy my file to, and SYSTEM is set to "all rights". Here is my trace :

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 58, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 51, in Main
    File "<string>", line 30, in DownCopy
    File "Z:\home\user\workspace\repo_config_os\temp-DwIWiG\build\pyi.win32\pyinstaller_build_all\out08-PYZ.pyz\urllib", line 93, in urlretrieve
    File "Z:\home\user\workspace\repo_config_os\temp-DwIWiG\build\pyi.win32\pyinstaller_build_all\out08-PYZ.pyz\urllib", line 243, in retrieve
  IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'IzznoLo.exe'
  ```

So the problem seem to be the downloading part. Is networking kind of restricted for SYSTEM ? Is there any way to allow "him" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two main approaches. The more constructive way is to make sure you catch the error messages, so first of all you need to redirect all the output to a file.

What you could try to fix the problem, is changing the permissions/ownership of the destination folder and loosen it up. Which way do you want to take?

It looks pretty clearly like the program "IzNoLo.exe" doesn't have global execution permissions set. To be honest, I don't know what that program does, but maybe you know it, is it something that you provide?

To set these [permissions], you would browse the properties panels, the security panel in particular and make sure all privileges are set, for all users.